# Bootstrap modal dialog not displaying/blacked out in firefox

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, dialog, modal-dialog

I'm trying to make a bootstrap modal dialog that works in Chrome an also works in Firefox (both latest versions). I have done some research and it seems that Firefox has a problem with displaying modal dialogs with the .fade class applied to it, although the dialog does show - I get a completely blacked out window pop up (with no content at all). When removing the .fade class from the HTML mark up the dialog doesn't display at all.

HTML involved:

```
 //Modal target <a>
<a data-target="#portfolioModal2" class="portfolio-link" data-toggle="modal">
<div class="caption">
<div class="caption-content">
    Project Title 2
</div>
</div>
</a>

 //The modal
 <div class="portfolio-modal modal" id="portfolioModal2" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="backgrid" data-dismiss="modal">
            <i class="icon ion-grid size-48"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="close-modal" data-dismiss="modal">
            <i class="icon ion-ios-close-empty size-96"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="container">
            <h2></h2>
            <hr>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-8">

                </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">

                <button type="button" class="border-button-black" data-dismiss="modal">CLOSE</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

    //Computed css values displayed in chrome console
    element {}
   .modal-backdrop.in {filter: alpha(opacity=50);opacity: .5;}
   .modal-backdrop.fade {filter: alpha(opacity=0);opacity: 0;}
   .fade.in {opacity: 1;}
   .modal-backdrop {position: fixed;top: 0;right: 0;bottom: 0;left: 0;z-index: 1040;background-color: #000;}
   .fade {opacity: 0;-webkit-transition: opacity .15s linear;-o-transition: opacity .15s linear;transition: opacity .15s linear;}* {margin: 0;padding: 0;opacity: 1 !important;}* {-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;-moz-box-sizing: border-box;box-sizing: border-box;}
  section, body {font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', 'Helvetica', 'Arial', 'sans-serif';font-weight: 400;font-size: 16px;color: black;}
body {font-family: "Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;font-size: 14px;line-height: 1.42857143;color: #333;}
```

Also just to note, when clicking the modal with the fade class applied and inspecting the blacked out window, it seems to be jumping to a node thats not defined anywhere in the mark-up with no content in it.

```
//The following is what the console finds when inspecting the dialog window
<div class="modal-backdrop fade in"></div>
```

I can't seem to find the problem so I was wondering if anyone could give me insight into what may be wrong, thanks!

Comment: Managed to fix this, seems polymer was interfering with the displaying of modal dialogs.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Can you specify the solution?